# Can I run my three-way travelers in a 14/2 without a neutral in the cable?

Tags: nec, multiway-switch

I have a surplus of 14/2 and a little bit of 14/3, and this project is price-sensitive, so I drew up this plan to make use of what I have on hand. It minimizes the length of 14/3 needed because that's all I have on hand. All switches and lights have neutrals and grounds accounted for - I just want to make sure I'm allowed to use a 14/2 cable as two travelers without a neutral.

[image: diagram]

Comment: No, see NEC 300.3.  /3 should go straight between the switches and need not stop at any lamps.  14/2 from either switch to the lamps.

Comment: I see, the issue is about impedance. Is this also the reason why a neutral is needed at the switch even if it is unused - the neutral picks up the induction  https://www.familyhandyman.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/how-to-wire-3-way-switch-2.jpg

Comment: That's not quite the issue. Neutral is required in new wiring to switches to allow for future upgrades to switches that need neutral, eg Smart, lit, timed switches.   The layout you drew satisfies that requirement but creates an asymmetric current path, which is not allowed.  You're not just adding an unused neutral to help with future upgrades. That would be good.  You're *using* a neutral in a way that creates a loop, not running in the same cable along the same path as the live conductor.  That's not good.    You shouldn't confuse/conflate the two requirements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not allowed because it violates the rule that in any cable there must be two conductors carrying equal current in opposite directions so the magnetic fields cancel. That T- T Loop top right would have one traveler carrying current, no current in the other, and no neutral present carrying current in the opposite direction.

The time varying magnetic field around the cable could induce currents in nearby conductors and cause heating.

EDIT

Since you are going to have to buy more cable, consider getting 14/4 + gnd and connecting the two switches in the arrangement called three-wire control. This gives a neutral and a constant line hot in both switch boxes. I recently came across an article¹ for a UK audience touting three wire control as superior to the traditional two wire control for connecting a pair of 3-way switches. I don't know if this is being done in the US.

The presence of both a line hot and a neutral in all switch boxes may be useful in the future, and the immediate benefit would be that you could easily extend the circuit to put a receptacle in the wall below. Such a receptacle would be independent of the two 3-way switches.

¹https://www.electronicshub.org/2-way-switch-wiring/

[image: Three wire control of pair of 3-way switches]

Comment: While I agree with the explanation, and you bring up very a good point, quantitatively  the OP or other readers need not panic, as there is not much cooking at only a few hundred mA of current, and quite a large loop area of at least 1/2in x 10ft.

Comment: +1, but heating is not the problem - not unless there are enough amps going through the cable to melt it.  The reason to avoid loops is entirely to do with EM noise pollution.

Comment: @J... Heating really is a problem. You might install a circuit with a 5W LED today. But the circuit, by definition, can handle 15A, 12A continuous. So the next owner might decide to put in a few hundred W of floodlights. Or reuse the existing wiring for a regular receptacle and plug in a 1500W heater. No way to predict future usage, so code is based on the maximum.

Comment: Is the magnetic field really a concern if all of the 14/2 is run together. I know that doesn't force them to be together, but I would expect them to be run together.

Comment: If a cable with unbalanced current enters a steel box, can it induce currents in the wall of the box that could cause heating?

Comment: All the K&T currently in my attic has kept my heating bills low ;)

Comment: @JimStewart Yes.  In systems where three phase power, for example, is fed to a junction box in individual conductors (common around 400A+ drops) I've seen small aluminum plates fitted over a punchout in the steel with the strain clamps also aluminum, presumably to mitigate this.  It can be a concern in EMT, also, at least at higher currents, so I'll perhaps temper some of my previous scepticism.

Comment: What you're describing is called a "California" or "Coast" 3-way in North American parlance -- it gives you always-hot and switched-hot at both ends at the price of not working with 4-way switching

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, how long has this "California" or "Coast" 3-way been in use there? Has its use spread to other US regions? Are there regions or jurisdictions of the US where it is prohibited?

Comment: @JimStewart -- it's been around for oh, 60-70 years best I can tell, maybe somewhat longer.  It's legal under the NEC most everywhere, although some folks mix it up with the *very* different *Carter* 3-way system, which was prohibited by the NEC way back in the bad old days when BX was the new hotness

Comment: I see your update with the diagram. Makes sense. I can install a light between the switches on the T2 and N wires. But I'd have to change out my junction boxes too, 9 wires is too much for my 1 1/2 octagon boxes. Seems wasteful to run this 14/4 AND have to run a 14/2 back to the lights again.

Comment: Are the pair of light fixtures in the ceiling between two wall switches or are the lights wall mounted and in the same wall as the switches? Are the two switches in the same wall?

Comment: The switches are on opposite walls of the same room. Lights are on the ceiling directly in the path between the switches. The 14/4 would be run right next to the lights anyway.

Comment: I am not invested in either way of wiring the switches, but if you wanted to do the "California 3-way", you could have the 14/4 cable go through a box accessible from the space above the ceiling and tap the T2 and N with a pair of 14/2 cables going to the two lights. There would be five separate wire nutted connections, including the ground which I have not shown in the diagram.

Comment: But making connections in boxes in an attic space is oftentimes not very pleasant so whichever way you wire this you might just want to use 14/2 cable from the last switch box to the light fixtures. That way all your connections are in boxes accessible from the interior living space.

Comment: I don't see how T2+N is a "California 3-way". T2 is a switched hot and the neutral is unswitched.

Comment: T2 is the permanent switched hot only with the California wiring (with T1 as line hot). With the standard wiring of two 3-way switches both T1 and T2 are just travelers and neither one is permanently the switched hot. So in the standard wiring you cannot tap a single traveler to get a switched hot.

Comment: The California 3-way is confusing. I think you should not even consider it. Just wire in the standard  way in which the only wires connecting the two switches to each other are the travelers in a 14/3 to carry the neutral. The common of one switch is connected to line hot and the common of the other switch is the switched hot going to the lights with a 14/2.

Answer (score 2):

### For the record, smart switches

In this case use smart switches that use wireless or powerline signaling, such as Insteon. The smart switch master goes at the left switch and the AC powered (but wireless communicating) remote goes on the right switch.

In this case the 14-2 between lamps has its black wire re-marked red using tape.

The 14-2 from the right lamp to the right switch is deleted altogether.

Now red = switched-hot, black = always-hot, white=neutral and Bob's your uncle.